# javascript caching (maybe)?

Tags: javascript

I have a need to remove an element from my screen and then regenerate an element with the same name.

In the code there is a deleteObject function and a appendChild call.

In the deleteObject function it is removing the element(s) by using the removeChild statement (as seen below).

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwtj9/10/) for what I'm trying to accomplish.  Right now the fiddle works but my code still does not.  I think it has to do with the "top" keyword.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923601/javascript-top-keyword) for my thoughts on that.

Like I said earlier I have an element called "container1" that needs to be removed and then I have a new "container1" that needs to be created.  When I remove the code out of the deleteObject function my new "container1" displays, however, when I include the code it appears to conflict and the new "container1" never gets displayed.

I'm wondering is there some sort of javascript caching that is going on?  As the remove and create functions are called back to back.  Is there a way that I can use the code that I have but add some sort of delay?

Any advice appreciated!

```
    function deleteObject(id) {
        try {
            var obj = document.getElementById(id);
            obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
        } catch (e) {}
        //do something
    }

function hidePopWin() {
    if (gPopupMask == null) {
        return;
    }

    deleteObject('popupMask_' + popuplayer);
    deleteObject('popcont_' + popuplayer);

    popuplayer--;

    if (popuplayer == 0) {
        gPopupIsShown = false;
        gPopupContainer = this.undefined;
        gPopupIframe = this.undefined;
    } else {
        var showmask = document.getElementById('popupMask_' + popuplayer);
        if (showmask) {
            showmask.style.display = "block";
            gPopupContainer = document.getElementById("popcont_" + popuplayer);
            gPopupIframe = document.getElementById("iframe_layer" + popuplayer);
        }
    }
    //console.log("got here: " )
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwtj9/10/) is more accurately displaying what is going on(however, in the fiddle it works, but internally it doesn't): See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923601/javascript-top-keyword) for further information

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No - I see both functions being called.  But the screen isn't representing the new container.

Comment: Can you describe the code you have in the jsFiddle?  It doesn't appear to function (there is no HTML) so we can run it to see how it works, so you need to explain what you want to happen and what is wrong.

Comment: the fiddle won't run, the calling code is too convoluted to get it running in fiddle.  basically the code in the fiddle is the removing and showing the popup div elements.  The problem is that I have to hide a div and then show a new div but it is called the same name.  So I'm hoping that the code in the fiddle will show a variable that is keeping the objects as it appears to not to destroy the original div that I'm trying to destroy.

Comment: @JeffV, Your question is very vague. Can you describe the expected behaviour, which doesn't occur? If it's hard to describe, can you create clear screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though trivial, perhaps you might have overlooked the DOM actually loading?
jsFiddle calls your code on `onLoad`.

If you call `deleteObject('id');`, it won't work until the after document/element has been loaded into the DOM, because the ID doesn't exist until then.

Answer (score 0):

There is no caching in javascript, but objects are not actually destroyed if you have a reference to them in a javascript variable (which it looks like you might in your sample code).

That alone shouldn't keep you from replacing the object in the DOM with another object so there must be something else going on.  You would have to include a more complete sample of the code you are asking about that causes the problem (including your HTML), for us to know how to advise your more specifically.

You can simplify the code you did include in your post by using this function:

```
function deleteObject(id) {
    try {
        var obj = document.getElementById(id);
        obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
    } catch(e) {}
}
```

Then, you can call this:

```
deleteObject('popupMask_' + popuplayer);
deleteObject('popcont_' + popuplayer);
```

And, this code does not keep a reference to the removed objects in any JS variable so the objects will be destroyed by the JS garbage collector.

Comment: Isn't catching errors quite inefficient when it comes to performances? Checking if `obj` isn't null should do the work.

Comment: I added a fiddle so you can see what I'm working with.  This code is pretty old and we are refactoring the surrounding project that is why this is all of a sudden not working.

Comment: When the expected result is no errors, setting one exception handler can be more efficient than multiple `if` checks and it's certainly smaller code and easier to read.  Throwing and catching an exception is slower than an `if` check.  In code like this, minor differences in performance are rarely an important consideration.  Reliability, readability, maintainability and size are usually more important considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried debugging that thing and it seems related to the removeChild method.

This fixes the issue - `setTimeout(function(){obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj)}, 5)`

The only explanation I can think of is that the `removeChild(iframe-obj)` is called from an event of the `iframe-obj`. So it is not possible to execute javascript code deleting the DOM element from which this code is executed (like `<div onclick="this.parent.removeChild(this)"...` - not going to remove itself).

This dependency is not obvious in the code, but probably it has something to do with the UI thread and the iframe being another document loaded at the same time. The setTimeout allows the script to run from different execution point (not the one preventing the iframe to be deleted) and so the `iframe-obj` get removed from the DOM.

That's interesting case.

Comment: I will give your code a go and see if it corrects the problem on my side.  Thank you for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: where would I put this in my code?  would it be where the removechild lines are?  Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a couple of things that you might want to consider changing. First, would you want to maintain a sort of state of the container you're adding/removing? Would it make more sense to use bubbling? It's sort of unclear what you're after. Are you asking how to remove an element and create a new element with the same id name? If that's the case then you might want to make that your first object you create in js.

```
var myDiv = function(data){id: id, init: function(data.id){document.createElement('div'), return init}

myDiv.init("id") //makes a new div!
```

Then your next object is the popup, etc...etc...

You know what? A good example of this is sticky notes, sans the localstorage hooks: http://www.webkit.org/demos/sticky-notes/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you'll be ok with this or not, but this is a way to handle:
When you already got the reference to the object you're trying to delete, just rename it and then delete. This will make the name in DOM not used, so after adding the new element, it will be unique by its name.